# Why is 0dp the same as wrap_content in this ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, xml

New to XML and was trying practising an XML lab (https://github.com/harshitha-akkaraju/layoutlab)

What confuses me is that even though the width of the button is 0dp, it is if the width was wrap_content. I know that 0dp is the equivalent of "MATCH_CONSTRAINT" in a ConstraintLayout. However, doesn't that mean that 0dp should fill as much space as possible?

Is it because the button only has a constraint defined on its left side, which is why 0dp = wrap_content in this case?

0dp, which is the equivalent of "MATCH_CONSTRAINT

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="1"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[Image of the Button Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wKeD.png)

Comment: Yeah, MATCH_CONSTRAINT is only useful if you've constrained both the start/end or top/bottom. You'd naturally want to do this anyway or else you're risking the view behaving in a way you don't want. e.g. overflowing outside the view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for the button to match the parent layout, you need to set two opposite constraints....as in

````xml
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
<!-- Since you are setting width as 0dp, i presume you want the width to match... -->
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="1"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
<!-- You must add here another constraint to the right -->
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>```
````

Comment: In the solution of the XML lab I am doing, the width isn't supposed to match. It's just supposed to be wrap_content, which I why I was confused. So when there is only one constraint, width=0dp works like wrap_content?

Comment: That isn't guaranteed that `0dp` will always wrap content...in fact, `0dp` is just something like an optimization for android to calculate size of views quickly... it will most cases make the view disappear from screen..that is giving it `0dp` of width....

Comment: I see, so is it considered bad style that the solution of the lab uses the code that I showed above (where android:layout_width="0dp" is seemingly meant to be android:layout_width="wrap_content" )?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing this line `app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"`
in your button `0dp` works with parent when

`app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"` and `app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"`

then width should be `0dp`and when

`app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` and `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"`

then height should be `0dp`